# how can I display my jframe on right component using javaSwing?

Tags: java, swing

```
private void PersonalInfoJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

    JPanel createUserJPanel =new CreateUserJPanel(user);
    JSplitPane.setRightComponent(createUserJPanel);

}
```

It was showing me error like `non-static method cannot be reffered to static component`

How can I display my jframe on right component??

Comment: Don't use static variables or methods in your program. Read the Swing tutorial for examples of how to structure you code. Maybe you can start with [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since [setRightComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setRightComponent%28java.awt.Component%29)  is not a `static` method , It is telling to create a `instance` to use that `method`.

like

```
final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
splitPane.setRightComponent(createUserJPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of a JSplitPane:

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
splitPane.setRightComponent(createUserJPanel);
```